# Unable to compile Python program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# blinking function
def blink(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)
    return

# to use Raspberry Pi board pin numbers  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# set up GPIO output channel  
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

# blink GPIO17 50 times  
for i in range(0,50):
    blink(4)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

The above mentioned code is giving error

> GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
>
> AttributeError: `module` object has no attribute `setmode`

Comment: Python has this nifty thing called **full tracebacks** that it posts when you get an error like this, which tell you **exactly what is wrong**. Why don't you either read it or post it?

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no error message given in the question, I copied & pasted the code.  I got "ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO". I'm guessing that you don't have the [RPIO module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPIO/0.10.0) installed.

Comment: i have installed the GPIO Module...but now the error is                     GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) AttributeError: module object has no attribute setmode

Comment: That's really a separate question.  Please post it as such.  And I don't have any experience with, or accesss to, a Raspberry Pi, so probably can't be of more help at this time.  Also, you seem new; there's a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) that will help acclimate you to the site.